Can not connect to Neon using Prisma
I created a new NextJs(v14) app, installed prisma(v5.16.1) and then created a new project on Neon.
I have added a .env file in my project and copied the Neon database connection string to it.
The connection string is: postgresql://[user]:[password].us-east-2.aws.neon.tech/expensedb?sslmode=require
I have added two models to the schema.primsa file. When I run "npx prisma generate" I get no erros. Afterwards, when I run "npx prisma migrate dev" I get a connection timed out error.

Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at ep-dark-frog-a501j4x2.us-east-2.aws.neon.tech:5432
Please make sure your database server is running at ep-dark-frog-a501j4x2.us-east-2.aws.neon.tech:5432.

I tried adding connect_timeout=300 to the connection string but then the connection just hangs.
Can someone please help with this...
If possible, please recreate the steps I have taken above and see if you run into the same issue.

Please check tag descriptions before adding. The [tag:neon] tag is for the ARM vector instruction set, not the database. There's a [tag:neon.tech] tag that maybe is correct here, but since I'm not sure and it has no description, I'm holding off.

For some reason, it worked for me when I connected through a VPN (US location).

So after trial and error I've found a working solution.
In the neon.tech home screen, go to the "overview" tab in the sidebar and select "Roles & Databases" tab. From there, create a new Role and a new Database, and then use the new details to generate the connection string from the "Dashboard" tab in the sidebar. Following this approach, I am not getting any errors and my connection doesn't hang either. Also note, I did not need to use the "connect_timeout" parameter in the connection string.
If anyone else was having this issue, hopefully this solution works for you too.

The issue you are facing has to deal with the formatting of your DATABASE_URL value in your .env file. What you need to do is add a ? and a timeout command after your url
update the value in your .env file like this
DATABASE_URL = 'url + ?sslaccept=strict&connect_timeout=500'

