Can't connnect to remote databases like supabase, mongodb atlas or neon db with prisma orm
I have the same problem with all my projetcs. When I work with local database like postgres or mongodb(whithin a docker container on my computer) it's works fine. But if I try to connect with remote database like mongo db atlas or supabase or neon I have this error
Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `ep-lively-bread-a2ujntlv.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech:5432`

Please make sure your database server is running at `ep-lively-bread-a2ujntlv.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech:5432`.
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.

Click to see the error in png
On other side, when I'm trying to connect to remote databases with psql, vscode database extension, mongo compas, it's work fine
To fix this error, I tried:

to reset the project,
use prisma templates,

So all my attempts have failed. This is a snippet from my prisma schema:
datasource db {
provider  = "postgresql"
url       = env("POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL") // uses connection pooling
directUrl = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING") // uses a direct connection

}
And this is the .env varibles for neon:
    POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL="postgres://default:[PASSWORD]@ep-lively-bread-a2ujntlv-pooler.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech:5432/verceldb?sslmode=require&pgbouncer=true&connect_timeout=15"

POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING="postgres://default:[PASSWORD]@ep-lively-bread-a2ujntlv.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech:5432/verceldb?sslmode=require"

Any ideas or fixes will be helpful

The issued is the protocol in your connection URL. It should be postgresql, not postgres. See doc here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/overview/databases/postgresql#connection-details

I tried this but I got the same error Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at ep-lively-bread-a2ujntlv.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech:5432
POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL="postgresql://default:[PASSWORD]@ep-lively-bread-a2ujntlv-pooler.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech:5432/verceldb?sslmode=require&pgbouncer=true&connect_timeout=15"

POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING="postgresql://default:[PASSWORD]@ep-lively-bread-a2ujntlv.eu-central-1.aws.neon.tech:5432/verceldb?sslmode=require"


Try with connect_timeout=30 or 0 for test connect from prisma.

@jlerocher Have same question at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78705101/can-not-connect-to-neon-using-prisma

I tried to with connect_timeout=0, 30, 50 100, 300, but I got the same error. This question doesn't work for me.

May be the issued at URL connection or Prisma lib, because in same compute u can't connect from Prisma but it worked with terminal or DB tool. Try create new project Nodejs connect with neon not use Prisma. If it works, upgrade to major Prisma.

I tried to connect with shared mobile data and it's work but on my wifi(home router network) I got the same error. Any ideas why it's happens?

Finally,with a VPN I'm able to connect to myremote databases. I think this was a bad config in my home network
